# Edit IIS Custom Response Header using Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis, azure-devops

I am writing a remote PowerShell script to use in Azure DevOps, the script is to edit an IIS HTTP Response Header for a specific site. The code below is to add it, but what I am missing is to edit an existing header.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration") | Out-Null
$iis = new-object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
$config = $iis.GetWebConfiguration("Test")
$httpProtocolSection = $config.GetSection("system.webServer/httpProtocol")
$customHeadersCollection = $httpProtocolSection.GetCollection("customHeaders")
$addElement = $customHeadersCollection.CreateElement("add")
$addElement["name"] = "X-Custom-Name"
$addElement["value"] = "xxx"
$customHeadersCollection.Add($addElement)
$iis.CommitChanges()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i added a remove before the add

```
$PSPath =  'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$(IISName)' 
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath $PSPath -Name . -Filter system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders -AtElement @{name ="X-Robots-Tag"}
```

Comment: Hi, very appreciate this solution shared here. You can accept this answer thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works:-)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a simpler approach.

To set the existing header `$headerName` to value: `$headerValue`

```
import-module WebAdministration
Set-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -Filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" `
    -PSPath IIS:\Sites\$siteName -Name . `
    -AtElement @{name=$headerName} `
    -Value @{name=$headerName;value=$headerValue}
```

To add the new header `$headerName` with value: `$headerValue`

```
import-module WebAdministration
Add-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -Filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" `
    -PSPath IIS:\Sites\$siteName -Name . `
    -AtElement @{name=$headerName} `
    -Value @{name=$headerName;value=$headerValue}
```

And for completeness, to get value of the existing header `$headerName`:

```
import-module WebAdministration
$customHeaders = Get-WebConfigurationProperty `
    -Filter "system.webServer/httpProtocol/customHeaders" `
    -PSPath IIS:\Sites\$siteName -Name . `
$customHeader = $customHeaders.Collection | where-object { $_.name -eq $headerName })
$headerValue = $customHeader.value
```